# php extension: how do I use the mb_* functions

Tags: php, multibyte

There's a lot of functionality available in PHP for scripts. Is this functionality available somehow to the extension writer? I'd really like to use the multibyte functions but can't find an example thereof.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take the [exif module](http://svn.php.net/viewvc/php/php-src/trunk/ext/exif/) as an example. It also depends on the mbstring module and calls its functions "directly", i.e. without something like [call_user_function_ex(...)](http://svn.php.net/viewvc/php/php-src/trunk/Zend/zend_API.h?revision=304408&view=markup#l440)

e.g.

```
ZEND_INI_MH(OnUpdateEncode)
{
#if EXIF_USE_MBSTRING
    if (new_value && strlen(new_value) && !php_mb_check_encoding_list(new_value TSRMLS_CC)) {
        php_error_docref(NULL TSRMLS_CC, E_WARNING, "Illegal encoding ignored: '%s'", new_value);
        return FAILURE;
    }
#endif
    return OnUpdateString(entry, new_value, new_value_length, mh_arg1, mh_arg2, mh_arg3, stage TSRMLS_CC);
}
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks very much! Big green tick for you!